# getting an 'invalid xml' error

Tags: xml, shopify

I'm trying to create an xml feed for a product feed list.  My end use will be to convert the xml feed to csv file for uploading into my ad provider.

However, when I try to convert the xml data to csv I get an "invalid xml" error. Can anyone point out the problem in the code which is causing me to get this error?

```html
{% layout none %}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="rss.css" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
    
        <atom:link href="{{shop.url}}/pages/product-feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        {% paginate collections.all-products.products by 200 %}{% for product in collections.all-products.products %}{% if product.type != 'Sample' %}
      <item>
             <id>{{product.id}}</id>
        <availability>In Stock</availability>
        <condition> New </condition>
        <description>{{product.description | strip_html | truncatewords: 2}}></description>
         <image_link>{{shop.url}}{{ image | product_img_url: 'medium' }} </image_link>
            <title>{{ product.title | strip_html }}></title>
         <link>{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}</link>
<price>{{product.price_max | divided_by: 100}} USD</price>
      <brand> Brand Name </brand>
      
           
       
            
           

        </item>
        {% endif %}{% endfor %}{% endpaginate %}
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score -1):

XML starting with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

is valid.

XML starting with

```
{% layout none %}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

is not.

Comment: the {% layout none%} is part of the liquid language that the CMS uses and does not display in the actual feed once published.

Comment: The current XML file is valid (except for the initial `{% .. %}`) so perhaps it becomes invalid only after the template placeholders are converted to the actual text. Do you have the *converted* XML available?